# Построение гистограмм в Chart

Tags: гистограммы, диаграммы, c#

Как работать с элементом Chart в Visual Studio? Нужно построить гистограмму, по оси Y числовые значения типа double в диапазоне от 0 до 1 (0,01, 0,005 и т.д), а по оси X символьные значения типа string (array simvol). Как это реализовать?

Я нашел как забить числовые значения для Y:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= t; j++)
{
    ...
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(chst1[j]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: piterstockman, я не могу по какой то причине добавить к вашему ответу комментарий, но дело не в названии) Я его в настройках Chart  как только не задавал... И ваш вариант не работает по этой же причине.. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] labels = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
int i = 0;
for (double y = 0.1; y < 1; y += 0.1)
{
     chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(y);
     chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel(i, i + 2, labels[i], 0, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark));
     i++;
}
```

Comment: Извините, но вылезают ошибки типа, "Ошибка 2 Не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен "CustomLabel" (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?)" и "Ошибка 3 Элемент "LabelMarkStyle" не существует в текущем контексте"... Что делать?

Comment: Все хорошо) Спасибо Вам!) Реши проблему таким образом:

 chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(i1,i1+2,labels[i1]);

Comment: У меня в программе есть главное окно, а есть вызываемые из него. Так вот в одном и вызываемых у меня строятся две таблицы и по ним гистограммы. В первом случае при попытке построить гистограмму он меня выкидывает сюда 

    Freq chast = new Freq();
    chast.Owner = this;
    chast.ShowDialog();

И пишет, что ссылка на  объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
Гистограмму строю так.

    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(chstSimvol1[i1]);
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(i1-1, i1+1, simvol1[i1]);

На этом куске она вылетает, а вторую строит нормально. Что это такое?

Comment: В первом случае забыл добавить, что нужно было прописать:
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
Хотя и в Вашем случае все хорошо работает.
Моя догадка, что ошибка может быть в названии у ChartArea, попробуйте так:
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(i1);               chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(i1, i1 + 2, simvol1[i1]);